# javascript confirm function ok and cancel return same result

Tags: javascript

Here, I am calling `confirm(param1, param2)` method to display an alert `Do you want to continue?`

In this case, if the user clicks `OK`, it returns `true`, if the user clicks `Cancel`, it returns `false`.

But, when Cancel button is clicked, it is calling `checkcount()` method.

My requirement is whenever the user clicks on `OK` button, it should call `checkcount()` method.

How to achieve this?

```
<script>
function call(param1, param2, param3)
{
    if (condition)
    {
       /*some process */
    }
    else
    {
       confirm(param1, param2);
       checkcount();
    }
}

function confirm(param1, param2)
{
    if(condition)
    {
       var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
       if (retVal == true)
       {
           alert("User wants to continue!");
           return true;
       } 
      else
      {
           alert("User does not want to continue!");
           return false;
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no check!

```
confirm(param1, param2);
checkcount();
```

and you want to change your function name to something other than confirm.

```
<script>
function call(param1, param2, param3)
{
    if (condition)
    {
       /*some process */
    }
    else
    {
        if(myConfirm(param1, param2)) {
            checkcount();
        }
    }
}

function myConfirm(param1, param2)
{
    if(condition)
    {
       var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
       if (retVal == true)
       {
           alert("User wants to continue!");
           return true;
       } 
      else
      {
           alert("User does not want to continue!");
           return false;
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `condition` may well be a placeholder for two different checks, but if it is true, `myConfirm()` won't get called, if it's not, the confirmation will never be shown. Just a thought. +1

Comment: Have you used `condition` as a placeholder for this question or is that a variable outside the two of these functions?

Comment: Actually, Instead of condition, it should be like param1>100. I used it for example purpose. Sorry for the typo