# javascript confirm function ok and cancel returns same result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here in `result()` method, whenever it comes to else part, I need to get out of the function callthis().

It should not execute `kumar()` function.

Is this possible?
Actually, I can use like this

```
if(result)          //if this method is true, it will come inside
{
    kumar();
}
```

But this is not I want. while returning false from `result()` method, it should get out of the loop `function calthis()`

```js
function calthis()
{
  var i=1;
  if(i==0)
  {
    alert("inside if");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("inside else");
    result();
    kumar();
  }

}
function result()
{
  var res = confirm("are you wish to continue");
  if(res==true)
  {
    return true;
    alert("inside if result");
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
function kumar()
{
  alert("inside kumar");
}
```

```html
<a href="" onclick="calthis();">Click here</a>
```

Comment: As an aside, you should stop using `alert` to trace the flow of execution through your code. Get used to using `console.log` or the actual debugger built into your browse, which will let you step through code one instruction at a time.

Comment: YOU JUST ASKED THIS AND IT HAS THE SAME PROBLEM!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805106/javascript-confirm-function-ok-and-cancel-return-same-result

Comment: epascarello: dont mistake me. In the previous question, I was asked wrongly..So only asked clearly again. and this is slightly different. as you said, you can use if(method that returns true). I used that too. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: It is still the same issue.

Comment: This question is somewhat different. return should come out of the function ..

Comment: The code is the same, all this solution did was move the function call into a different function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch wrong here.

First, `if (result)` just tests whether the variable `result` contains a truthy value, it doesn't actually invoke the function. If you want to test the return value of the function, you need

```
if (result()) {
```

Secondly, you're not understanding that `return` *immediately* leaves the current function. You can't meaningfully do this:

```
if(res==true)
{
return true;
alert("inside if result");
}
```

That `alert` cannot be reached. The function returns immediately when `return true` is encountered.

Thirdly, to exit `callThis` early, you simply need to `return` early. It's up to the function `callThis` to conditionally return; you cannot force a return from down inside the `result` function. A function cannot forcibly return out if the context that called it. It's not up to the internals of the `result` function to determine if `kumar` should run. You cannot influence the path of execution in the calling method directly. All `result` can do is return something, or (needlessly complex in this case) accept a callback and conditionally execute it.

Just `return` from `callThis` if the result of `result()` is false:

```
function calthis()
{
  var i=1;
  if(i==0)
  {
    alert("inside if");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("inside else");
    if (!result()) return;
    kumar();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you...I got it..+1 for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To exit any function simply use `return;`

However it seems like you want to call a function if the user clicks confirm, is that correct?  If so:

```
var res = confirm("are you wish to continue");
if (res === true) 
{ 
   kumar(); 
}
```

If you want to call a function if the user does not click confirm:

```
var res = confirm("are you wish to continue");
if (!res) 
{ 
   kumar(); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You got a lot of confusing code going on there, but if the idea is to stop a function, simply use "**return false;**" and the code execution stops