# How Can i redirect to another PHP Page when i Confirm using Javascript without using PHP header Function

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP page called Course Enrollment where the student can enrol in a course or cancel his enrollment. when the user cancel his enrollment I made a javascript function called confirmDelete() that send a confirmation message before deletion. if the user pressed OK then it will redirect the user to deleteEnrollment.php (where I execute the deletion) if the user pressed cancel then do nothing.

The Course_Enrollment.php has the below code

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>

function confirmDelete() {
  if (confirm("Do you really want to delete your Enrollment?")) {
    window.location.href = "includes/deleteEnrollment.php";
    return;
  } 
}
  </script>
 <form action="" method="post" role="form">
              <button type="submit" name="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="confirmDelete()">Cancel Enrollment</button>
```

when I run the above code nothing happened. i don't know the reason. when I change window.location.href with header("location:includes/deleteEnrollment.php"); it works fine but I don't want to use header because if the user press yes or no the PHP code will execute.

Where is the issue in my code?..

Comment: `language=JavaScript` is no longer used by any modern browser

Comment: Confirmation Popup Appearing?

Comment: I found the answer under this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083626/redirect-to-another-page-after-confirm-and-post-values

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="" method="post" role="form">
    <button type="submit" name="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirmDelete()">Cancel Enrollment</button>
</form>

<script type="application/javascript">
function confirmDelete() {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to delete your Enrollment?")) {
        window.location.href = "includes/deleteEnrollment.php";
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Add `return` to `onclick` and also add `return` to JavaScript function.

[See it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/5o3902dq/)

Comment: Yes it's working. May i ask why we need return false ?

Comment: @mhussein76 Return `false` is like do nothing and stop working after that. The `onclick` attribute must `return` and follow with function while in function `return false;` to prevent `form` from submit.

Answer (score 1):

You are not submitting any form data with that button so the button type should not be `submit`. Change the button type to `button` or `reset` and it will work, e.g.: `type="button"`. Also, you don't need the `return` statement.

This has already been answered: [window.location.href doesn't redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759020/window-location-href-doesnt-redirect)